# Can funnels be configured based on screen events?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I am using firebase Analytics for iOS and Android. I just want to check weather Can I use funnel for screen based events or not? I know  we can create up to 200 funnels per project from [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317523?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnels can be created with events - so `screen_view` can be used in a funnel. However, you can't create a funnel for certain parameters. If you want to identify a specific page progress, you could use custom events for that.